# LibGit2Sharp implementation of showbranch independent

Tags: c#, git, libgit2, libgit2sharp

I'm trying to use LibGit2Sharp to recreate the functionality of `git show-brach --independent` which, according to the [docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-show-branch#git-show-branch---independent) does this: `Among the <reference>s given, display only the ones that cannot be reached from any other <reference>.`

My best attempt so far is the following:

```
    List<Commit> GetIndependent(IRepository repo, IEnumerable<Commit> commits)
    {
        var indep = new List<Commit>();

        foreach (var commit in commits)
        {
            if (repo.Commits.QueryBy(new CommitFilter
            {
                FirstParentOnly = false,
                IncludeReachableFrom = commit,
                ExcludeReachableFrom = commits.Where(x => x.Equals(commit) == false)
            }).Any())
            {
                indep.Add(commit);
            }
        }

        return indep;
    }
```

Unfortunately, this becomes astronomically slow as the amount of history increases. It's actually much faster for me to exec git directly, parse the output, and have LibGit2Sharp lookup the resulting SHAs than to use the above code. I assume this has to do with some optimization that Git has but LibGit2 does not. Is this even doing what I want? If so, is there a better way to achieve this in LibGit2Sharp?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found a better way that utilizes merge bases, thanks to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31527908/how-to-list-branches-that-contain-a-given-commit-in-git2go-libgit2) pointing me in the right direction.

Here's the new code:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Implementation of `git show-branch --indepenent`
    /// 
    /// "Among the <reference>s given, display only the ones that cannot be reached from any other <reference>"
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="commitsToCheck"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    private List<Commit> GetIndependent(IRepository repo, IEnumerable<Commit> commitsToCheck)
    {
        var commitList = commitsToCheck.ToList();

        for (var i = commitList.Count - 1; i > 0; --i)
        {
            var first = commitList[i];
            for (var j = commitList.Count - 1; j >= 0; --j)
            {
                if (i == j) continue;

                var second = commitList[j];

                var mergeBase = repo.ObjectDatabase.FindMergeBase(first, second);

                if (first.Equals(mergeBase))
                {
                    // First commit (i) is reachable from second (j), so drop i
                    commitList.RemoveAt(i);

                    // No reason to check anything else against this commit
                    j = -1;
                } else if (second.Equals(mergeBase))
                {
                    // Second (j) is reachable from first, so drop j
                    commitList.RemoveAt(j);

                    // If this was at a lower index than i, dec i since we shifted one down
                    if (j < i)
                    {
                        --i;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return commitList;
    }
```